# Is it possible to create a new object in Python while the program is running without using stdin?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if that is a good title, so allow me to better explain what I am trying to do...

My Python program is running in a Docker container on a local server. It has a website that is hosted on a web server. The Python program can FTP files in/out of the web server. The JavaScript will take user input and save it to a file on the web server via FTP. The Python program will poll this file periodically for changes. When there is a change, I want to use that change to create a new object and insert it into a list of existing objects, all while the program is looping through that list of objects.

The way [I'm currently doing it](https://github.com/anthonyLuttrell/RedditStatsBot/blob/master/scanner_pool.py) is all of the objects are created when the program first starts, and that's it. I want to be able to go to the website, type in a string, then the program will eventually see that new string and use it to create a new `Scanner` object using this string for `name` in `scanner_class_builder`, then append it to a list of `Scanner` objects that I am looping through.

Comment: That sounds like a perfectly reasonable approach. What issues are you running into?

Comment: @MegaIng - For some reason it took reading your comment for this to click in my head that I can just implement this as I've written it. For some reason I thought I was missing some pieces to the puzzle. So your comment may actually be the best answer lol

Answer (score -8):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

## Create an instance of MyClass

```
my_object = MyClass(value=42)
```

## Create a dictionary

```
my_dict = {'key': 'value'}
```

## Create a list

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

## Create a new class dynamically

```
dynamic_class = type('DynamicClass', (), {'attribute': 'value'})
```

## Create an instance of the dynamically created class

```
dynamic_object = dynamic_class()
```

## Create a new object using the object() constructor

```
my_object = object()
```

These examples demonstrate different ways to create objects in Python.

The choice of which method to use depends on your specific requirements and the nature of the objects you need to create.

Comment: Why would you use ChatGPT to answer on Stack Overflow? That's not how Stack Overflow is supposed to be.